# Data binding: how to solve 'Could not find accessor' issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I am using data binding library for binding data in recyclerview but I keep getting the below error,  I don't understand where is the mistake, I have checked my code several times and also I have tried all the possible solutions from the internet but nothing is working. Kindly help me to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance.

Error

```
Could not find accessor com.apis.models.MoviesPageModel.movies
at android.databinding.tool.util.L.printMessage(L.java:134)
at android.databinding.tool.util.L.e(L.java:107)
```

viewmodel

```
class MoviesPageModel(private val api: ServiceApi): BaseViewModel()  {

private val _moviesList: MutableLiveData<List<Section>> = NotNullMutableLiveData(arrayListOf())
val movies: MutableLiveData<List<Section>> get() = _moviesList

fun getMovies() {
    addToDisposable(api.getMoviesRE().with()
        .doOnSubscribe {}
        .doOnSuccess {}
        .doOnError {}.subscribe({

            if(it != null){
                _moviesList.value = it.Sections
             }
        }, {
        })
    )
   }
 }
```

xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>
    <variable
        name="vm" type="com.models.MoviesPageModel" />
</data>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui_fragments.Movies">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:moviesAdapter="@{vm.movies}"
        app:viewModel="@{vm}" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### How to fix the issue?

Rename either `movies` variable or `getMovies` method to something else. I'd rename the method to `requestMovies`.

### Explanation

In your case, the issue is the naming of class members of the `MoviesPageModel` class. Remember that Kotlin produces Java-compatible bytecode, it could be simply understood as - "Kotlin is compiled to Java", sort of.

When you create in Kotlin a class-level variable named `movies` with a getter it is compiled to a Java-like method.

Here is a strip down version of your class. Only declarations are left so we can focus on the problem:

```
class MoviesPageModel(): ViewModel()  {

    private val _moviesList: MutableLiveData<List<Object>> = MutableLiveData(arrayListOf())
    val movies: MutableLiveData<List<Object>> get() = _moviesList

    fun getMovies() {
    }
}
```

Kotlin understands `movies` as a variable and it doesn't give any hints to the outer world that `movies` is actually just a getter for `_moviesList`.

Now, let's look at how compiled to bytecode and decompiled back to **Java** this code will look like. This is what ends up in your program and runs on a selected machine:

```
public final class MoviesPageModel extends ViewModel {
   private final MutableLiveData _moviesList;

   @NotNull
   public final MutableLiveData getMovies() {
      return this._moviesList;
   }

   public final void getMovies() {
   }

   public MoviesPageModel() {
      boolean var1 = false;
      this._moviesList = new MutableLiveData(new ArrayList());
   }
}
```

Notice something? There is no `movies` variable! It was replaced with:

```
public final MutableLiveData getMovies()
```

But here is the problem! You already had `getMovies` method. This code in Java produces a compile-time error (while Kotlin analogue exists without a warning):

[image: Two getMovies() methods in a class! Not allowed!]

That is the reason for this error:

```
Could not find accessor com.apis.models.MoviesPageModel.movies
```

Comment: Thank you soooo muchhhh for highlighting and this detailed explanation.